# How to add the redirect Url in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am not good with ColdFusion currently I have a `.htAccess` file which i need to write a redirect to the following url 
`http:users.planningresource.co.uk/profession/students` to the some other url like `/basic/registration`.

Can anyone help me!

Comment: You can add a redirect rule in the .htaccess file or can add a redirect in the Application.cfc request handler for that URL.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is nothing to do with ColdFusion. It's a web server configuration.